# Float equality tolerance for single and half precision

Tags: python, numpy, precision

Suppose the metric is

```py
abs(a-b) <= rtol * max(abs(a), abs(b))
```

i.e. [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) with `atol=0`. The default for `float64` is `rtol=1e-9`. [`numpy.allclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) uses `rtol=1e-5`.

Both `1e-9` and `1e-5` make sense to me for `float64`, depending on application - former for stricter equality, latter for engineeresque "good enough". What I seek to know is, **what are their `float32` and `float16` equivalents?** How about `10 ** (floor(log10(2 ** (-(mantissa_bits + 1) / 2))) - 1)` (see (3) below)?

Seeking references, or simply reasoning also works. Below discussion self-admits to lacking a thorough look into this matter, yet numeric computation is an entire field, so I figure there must be something of sort for the most rudimentary task.

---

#### `math.isclose` rationale

[PEP 485](https://peps.python.org/pep-0485/) carefully explains it, including (1) the [default](https://peps.python.org/pep-0485/#relative-tolerance-default) `rtol=1e-9`; and, acknowledging that (2) no sensible default exists for `atol`, (3) ULP may be more appropriate depending on use case. It also describes [alternate proposals](https://peps.python.org/pep-0485/#alternate-proposals) to deal with `atol` issues. Further tolerance selection rationale is described in the [Boost project](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/test/doc/components/test_tools/floating_point_comparison.html).

**For sake of this question, ignore `atol`, assume `a != 0 && b != 0`.**

#### A discussion

Highlights from [numpy.isclose vs math.isclose](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10161):

**(1)** [`atol=1e-8` is bad](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10161#issuecomment-350021545) unless all input values are on order of unity. `np.allclose(1e-9, 2e-9)` is `True`.

**(2)** [`math.isclose` author](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10161#issuecomment-852585791):

> Note that the relative tolerance of 1e-8 was not only about half the
> precision of a float64, but also was large enough that there would be no
> difference in the results for various methods of comparison -- i.e. it
> really didn't matter which approach was taken -- again, fewer surprises.

**(3)** [Proposed other-precision tolerances](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10161#issuecomment-852783433)

[image]

#### Clarification

Relative error is *by definition* the goal. We seek a metric that is (1) robust, (2) order-of-magnitude independent, (3) readily configurable for tasks involving real-world data (known noise threshold). "Robust" defined as error variance matching data variance (so variability not induced by float limitations). `rtol` fails (1) near float epsilon, hence the need for `atol`.

Concerning defaults, it's easy to agree that generally, 1% is too weak, and $10^{-20}$% is too strong. A general purpose default can be derived via numeric simulations that sweep many common operations on different input sizes - repeated `fft`, squaring, square rooting, adding, multiplying. Example (full code at bottom):

```py
x0, x1 = randn(size), randn(size)  # float64
out0 = cast(op(x0, x1), 'float16')
out1 = op(cast(x0, 'float16'), cast(x1, 'float16'))
err = abs(1 - out1/out0)
```

```py
size = 100
float32 3.03e-08
float16 1.17e-04

size = 10000
float32 2.91e-08
float16 1.92e-05
```

This'd be done separately for GPUs per significant multithreading-induced error, hence different defaults. A user setting their own defaults is far more error prone. Those knowledgeable enough won't need defaults in the first place - but they also benefit per not having to set new thresholds for every new task, also having a reference (if new th is much greater or lower, think twice).

We'd also have to graph error vs number of operations, and it must be sufficiently stable up to a "reasonable" # of ops. I've just done some brief testing with my aforementioned operations, and it's indeed such. What's "reasonable" can be determined by surveying many real-world applications.

#### Example's code

```py
from numpy.random import seed, randn
from numpy import sqrt, sign

for N in (100, 10000):
    print("size =", N)
    for prec in ('float32', 'float16'):
        # seed for reproducibility; generate data
        seed(0)
        x0, x1 = randn(N), randn(N)
        x0p, x1p = x0.astype(prec), x1.astype(prec)
        
        # float64 ground truth, cast to `prec` after computation
        x0 = x0**2 * sign(x0)
        x1 = sqrt(abs(x1))
        o = sum(x0 * x1).astype(prec)
        
        # fully lower precision computation
        x0p = x0p**2 * sign(x0p)
        x1p = sqrt(abs(x1p))
        op = sum(x0p * x1p)
        
        print(prec, "%.2e" % abs(1 - o/op))
```

Comment: The proposal looks good to me. I'm not sure what more there is to add that isn't in the thread. It's also "just" a default value, anyone can of course pick what's right for them. I don't think any value of `rtol` or `rtol` can ever be *bad*. Absolute tolerance does exactly what it is supposed to. How else would you check if a value is close to zero?

Comment: @njuffa _"based on a maximum ulp difference"_ meaning what, exactly? What's the formula?

Comment: @MikaelÖhman `rtol` is closely equivalent to measuring error in significant figures. `atol`, particularly `1e-8` for `float64`, is troubling since it's nowhere near zero, and gives false positives (as shown in **(1)**). I favor `math.isclose`'s formulation in that it seems to closely resemble a conditional check - `if max(abs(a), abs(b)) < eps: use_atol()`.

Comment: @njuffa Thanks, though I don't know about bound independence, compute errors grow faster at lower precision. I also don't follow your concern on relative error. It's indeed very useful mathematically (the analogue is relative Euclidean distance, often invoked in theorems) and anytime there's expected significant figures, and I don't see what contexts it wouldn't be useful in, aside near float epsilon.

Comment: @njuffa It's a normalized error measure, essentially in percents. Percents are easily interpretable and configurable, if not essentially universal. I'm quite surprised you take this much an issue with it - I'll open a separate question if you're willing to elaborate. Note, it's simply `abs(a-b)/abs(a) > rtol` (simplified & rewritten), so distance between `a` and `b` that's adjusted for `a`'s norm. [Wavelet scattering](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/78513/50076) theorems use relative Euclidean distance, `sqrt(sum(abs(a - b)**2) / sum(abs(a)**2))`. I'm not aware specifically on `isclose`.

Comment: (yes there's significant differences vs rel-L2 but basic idea's same) -- also if I learn that your method's significantly advantageous, I'll firstly adjust my numeric testing (which are plentiful and accuracy is high priority), but also might pull request it to NumPy, a very influential library (maybe greatest in Python for scientific computing).

Comment: You can't "show" that a number is or isn't absolutely close to zero. It's entirely subjective and dependent on what the numbers measure and different in every application. Maybe you are measuring the velocity of vehicles in km/h, then of course `1e-8` is an absolute miniscule number. If happening to be measuring a strain in a diamond, it's an enormous number. It has no relation to the floating point type. That is precisely why `atol > 0` always an opt-in. `math.isclose` does *not* use `max(abs(a), abs(b)) < eps` since `eps` must be a function of a reference value; which you have to provide.

Comment: @MikaelÖhman I disagree. `rtol` handles the order of magnitude, `atol` handles numeric instability. I've updated the question. NumPy's `allclose`, despite being self-admittedly flawed, is the gold standard used in most Python packages - and there's packages for signal processing and machine learning, two heavily numerically intense fields. Despite the flaws, it works remarkably well. So all these "problems" seem heavily exaggerated, which is strange to hear from field experts...

Comment: `rtol` and `atol` is for whatever your application decides to use it for. `atol` is also the *only* option for comparing to zero, and there can never be a global `eps` or `atol` that applies to all, it's a function that takes your user supplied reference value. Fortunately, none of the `*close` implementations discussed ever use anything like `max(abs(a), abs(b)) < eps`. Magnitude has no impact on numeric stability with floating point numbers, you have as much accuracy at `1.23e-100 + 4.56e-100` as you have at `1.23e100 + 4.56e100`

Comment: @MikaelÖhman _you have as much accuracy_ yes, I was referring to dynamic range. "depends on application" is a true but useless answer. Again, we have suboptimal metrics with suboptimal thresholds that validate world-changing algorithms like ChatGPT. It really boggles my mind how the field of numeric computation doesn't concern itself with setting standards on float accuracy. The approach for setting said standards is I think very reasonably described under my "Clarification", and the results would by no means claim themselves as "absolute", like all "defaults"...

Comment: Well, I lie, I totally forgot about dynamic range in my `atol` comments... I'll need to rethink that -- also by the "it depends" logic there'd be no way to even have an `exp` or `sqrt` that simply works, one'd have to pass in a precision tolerance parameter - instead we don't even have said option in NumPy and MATLAB. And the two don't have identical implementations for said things, so they had to set their own standards for the number of approximation terms used.

Comment: @MikaelÖhman Ok, I agree there's no satisfactory, input-independent default for `atol` - if we must choose, I can't think of better than what `math` or `numpy` figured out. Yet I can imagine a `atol="auto"` that uses an input-dependent heuristic. Regardless for sake of this question, pretend inputs are non-zero.

Answer (score 4):

Those proposed tolerances look fine, but in my (opinionated) view this is really a problem with no satisfying solution, as the comments also argue.

For most algorithms, the error bounds one gets look like $O(n^p\mathsf{u})$, where $\mathsf{u}$ is the machine precision (ulp, `eps(1.0)`) and $n$ is the problem size. Often, the worst-case $p$ is larger than the average-case $p$, for instance for summation $p_{worst}=1$ and $p_{average}=1/2$. For linear algebra algorithms, the worst-case exponents might be larger, for instance $p=2$, but typically the average-case ones are still linear or less.

In particular, that $n$ means that the expected error level is very problem-dependent, and it is tricky to decide on a sensible default without knowing $n$.

The idea behind $10^{-8}$ is that it is a quantity that figures to be (1) larger than any $O(n^p \mathsf{u})$ you might reasonably encounter, but (2) small enough to avoid that different numbers erroneously compare as equal.

The good thing about double precision is that you have enough digits to satisfy (1) and (2) at the same time. With fewer digits available in your number type, those requirements are in conflict: there simply is no `rtol` that satisfies both (1) for a wide variety of problems and (2).

This issue seems fundamental to me: double precision is a sensible default; if you want to go lower, you *will* start to feel cramped. If you want to save on computational costs by skimping on precision you need to turn your brain on and be careful about numerical errors, so that your computation does not produce garbage. If you don't understand the errors in your algorithm well enough to even decide a sensible default tolerance, you're going to have much bigger problems in the rest of your work.

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate on what "problem size" means (input size)? And how the $p$'s are determined. Concerning float32 and float16, there's certainly been significant work done in both, since PyTorch and TensorFlow default to 32 and support 16, and much work was put in by NVIDIA and other researchers in making even 16 work, which of course wouldn't be possible without tolerances. Deep neural networks involve a ton of computations, but supporting 16 requires also handling fewer compute. So I guess I should look there. I just expected someone in this network to have such references handy.

Comment: _(Off-topic)_ I'm actually not at all happy with NumPy's default `atol=1e-8` with assuming "on order of 1". I've done a lot of signal processing work and have a strong sense of what qualifies as "zero" for data on order of 1 - it's at most `1e-15` for float64. `1e-8` is good if you're trying to test if an individual array - a set of measurements - is close to zero, rather than for _comparing_ two arrays which are supposed to be float-equal. The current heuristic I'm thinking of is `atol = median(abs(x))) / 1e15` - and just settle on one of `a` or `b` since if they're "equal" it won't matter

Comment: [Ongoing discussion](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10161#issuecomment-1676351141) for those interested

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon For summation, $n$ is the number of elements you wish to compute the sum of. For linear algebra, the matrix size. If you want to study more, Higham's *Accuracy and stability of numerical algorithms* is a good encyclopedic book on the classic algorithms. I know there has been a lot of work on single, half and even quarter precision recently; I agree that it is an area with a lot of potential, but still I think it is impossible to come up with a one-size-fits-all tolerance and careful analysis is needed.